# Is there a name for the probability distribution with the form $p(x) = a \,x^2\, \exp( -b\,x^2 )$

Tags: probability-distributions

There is a probability distribution:
$$p(x) =  a \,x^2\, \exp( -b\,x^2 ), \quad a,b>0,\ x \in ( -\infty,\,\infty )  $$
I wonder which probability distribution is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the correct scaling it is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_distribution

Comment: I forgot to mension $x \in ( -\infty,\,\infty )$. Does it still belong to Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: I don't think so. But are you sure that in your context negative $x$ are meaningful? (The PDF is an even function.)